# sql query for changing values depends on id

Tags: mysql

First of all some database cut:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------+----------+--------+
| id  | name                                   | code     | parent |
+-----+----------------------------------------+----------+--------+
|   1 | Basic Materials                        |      101 |   NULL |
|   2 | Consumer Cyclical                      |      102 |   NULL |
|   3 | Financial Services                     |      103 |   NULL |
|   4 | Real Estate                            |      104 |   NULL |
|   5 | Consumer Defensive                     |      205 |   NULL |
|   6 | Healthcare                             |      206 |   NULL |
|   7 | Utilities                              |      207 |   NULL |
|   8 | Communication Services                 |      308 |   NULL |
|   9 | Energy                                 |      309 |   NULL |
|  10 | Industrials                            |      310 |   NULL |
|  11 | Technology                             |      311 |   NULL |
|  12 | Agriculture                            |    10101 |    101 |
|  13 | Agricultural Inputs                    | 10101001 |  10101 |
|  14 | Building Materials                     |    10102 |    101 |
|  15 | Building Materials                     | 10102002 |  10102 |
|  16 | Chemicals                              |    10103 |    101 |
|  17 | Chemicals                              | 10103003 |  10103 |
|  18 | Specialty Chemicals                    | 10103004 |  10103 |
|  19 | Coal                                   |    10104 |    101 |
|  20 | Forest Products                        |    10105 |    101 |
|  21 | Lumber & Wood Production               | 10105006 |  10105 |
|  22 | Paper & Paper Products                 | 10105007 |  10105 |
|  23 | Metals & Mining                        |    10106 |    101 |
|  24 | Aluminum                               | 10106008 |  10106 |
|  25 | Copper                                 | 10106009 |  10106 |
|  26 | Gold                                   | 10106010 |  10106 |
|  27 | Industrial Metals & Minerals           | 10106011 |  10106 |
|  28 | Silver                                 | 10106012 |  10106 |
|  29 | Steel                                  |    10107 |    101 |
|  30 | Coal                                   | 10104005 |  10104 |
```

So now in parent column must be id column values where parent = code. I was trying do this but I can't figure this out by myself.

For example:

In row with id = 12 in parent column there should be value = 1 because in code column there is the same value as in parent column.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include **attempted solutions**, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update table as a 
left join table as b 
on a.parent=b.code 
set a.parent=b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a self-join with the multiple table `UPDATE` syntax:

```
UPDATE my_table a JOIN my_table b ON b.code = a.parent SET a.parent = b.id;
```

You may then wish to define a foreign key constraint on the altered table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES my_table (id);
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3057/1).

However, you should bear in mind that MySQL does not support recursive functions, so is not well suited to this adjacency-list model of representing hierarchical data: you may wish to consider the nested-sets or transitive-closure models instead.